# jekyll debug or print all variables

Tags: ruby, debugging, jekyll

I want to peak into Jekyll's brain and see what's going on, in php you have [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php), so I tried to do something akin to that with:

```
      {% for local_variable in local_variables %}
      <p> {{ local_variable }} </p><br>
      {% endfor %}
```

Which output nothing. Am I trying too hard? Is there some method in ruby or jekyll for this?  I'd just like to poke around and make sure everything is set correctly and possibly to find out about variables I don't know about.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

With Jekyll 2.x, you can use [this plugin](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/progrium/blogrium/master/_plugins/debug.rb).

It allows you to do something like `{{ site | debug }}`.

Since Jekyll 3, you have `{{ variable | inspect }}`.

Answer (score 41):

`inspect` doesn't let you peek inside variables, where `jsonify` does just that.

```
{{ variable | jsonify }}
```

No plugins needed.

Please be aware that `jsonify` will use as much memory it needs to do its thing without any specific limits. Say, if you have hundreds of posts or pages, and you would want to jsonify them all at once, this may not work as you expect. Worst case the system may go out of RAM and became unresponsive. Exercise due caution.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers don't address the “all variables” part of the question.

Although Jekyll doesn't offer a `get_defined_vars` equivalent, [the documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/) does declare [all available global variables](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#global-variables) (which at this time are `site`, `page`, `layout`, `content`, and `paginator`).

You can therefore debug/print **all** variables with a series of `jsonify` [filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) calls (filtering also with `escape` since some of them will contain HTML):

```
<pre>
    site: {{ site | jsonify | escape }}
    page: {{ page | jsonify | escape }}
    layout: {{ layout | jsonify | escape }}
    content: {{ content | jsonify | escape }}
    paginator: {{ paginator | jsonify | escape }}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

To pretty-print variables, you can insert this in any template:

```html
<pre id="jekyll-debug"></pre>
<script>
  var obj = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("{{ site | jsonify | uri_escape }}"));
  var prettyJson = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4);  // Pretty-printed JSON (indented 4 spaces).
  document.getElementById("jekyll-debug").textContent = prettyJson;
</script>
```

Change `site` (in `{{ site | jsonify | uri_escape }}`) to whatever variable you want to print.

You will then be able to see your variables neatly arranged in the generated pages. Something like this:

[image: Pretty-printed Jekyll template variables]

Answer (score 0):

For future, who see this page.

I have wrote a Package to do this type of work. In your command line, install it,

```
gem install 'jekyll-liquid-debug'
```

Then you can **debug** your `liquid` file in your terminal without **building your whole site** again and again.

By using,

```
jekyll-liquid-debug -f YOUR_LIQUID_FILE.liquid
```

It also has other usages, please check it more~